# selecting related data from database with select option, php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, html

Database Table "Product" has a "Product_Code" and "Product_Name"

We have a form where we fill Product Data

Select options are fetched from Database table column "Product_Code"

```
<select name="Select_Product_Code" id="Select_Product_Code"> 
    <option value="0">Product</option>
        <?php
             $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user1db','userdb','1db');
    if (!$con) {    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));    }
    mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Product";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {
            ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo($row['Product_Code'])?>" >
                <?php echo($row['Product_Code']);
                 ?>
            </option>
            <?php 
            } 
            ?>
    </select>
```

Without Form submit, Is there a way to show "Product_Name" in a Label or TextInput when "Product_Code" is selected ?

Edit , added ajax.

readproduct.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showProduct(str) {
  if (str=="") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } 
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getproduct.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<select name="products" onchange="showProduct(this.value)">
<option value="">Select </option>
<option value="1">0001</option>
<option value="2">0002</option>
<option value="3">0003</option>
<option value="4">0004</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>list</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

getproduct.php as follows

```
    <?php
    $q = intval($_GET['q']);
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user1db','userdb','1db');
    if (!$con) 
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "Connected";
    mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE Product_Code = '".$q."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        echo $row['Product_Name'];
    }
    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

If we remove where clause, all products names are displayed,
with where clause, getproduct.php does not display Product_Names. 
What we missed or did wrong?

Comment: You can show this with jquery very easily

Comment: Look into AJAX.

Comment: Either build elements on the page that are hidden until a selection is made then display the label/input you want...or use AJAX and select the relevant DB data.

Comment: We have used ajax php,   xmlhttp.open("GET","getproduct.php?q="+str,true); connects database but does not pass "q", or may be getproduct.php is incorrectly coded.

Comment: @MD.JubairMizan can you link me fiddle or example?

Answer (score 0):

You can populate an array inside your while loop that will be used later in a change listener for the select element like so:

```
<select name="Select_Product_Code" id="Select_Product_Code"> 
    <option value="0">Product</option>
        <?php
             $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','user1db','userdb','1db');
    if (!$con) {    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));    }
    mysqli_select_db($con,"ajax_demo");
    $sql="SELECT * FROM Product";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
            {

// here it adds a name with a key that matches the option-value
            $names[$row['Product_Code']] = $row['Product_Name'];

            ?>
            <option value = "<?php echo($row['Product_Code'])?>" >
                <?php echo($row['Product_Code']);
                 ?>
            </option>
            <?php 
            } 
            ?>
    </select>

<input type="text" id="out-text" value="The Name will appear here" />

<!-- then it populates the array with json_encode() to be used in the event-listener (both below) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var names = <?php echo json_encode($names); ?>;

document.getElementById("Select_Product_Code").addEventListener(
     'change',
     function() { 
        document.getElementById("out-text").value = names[this.selectedIndex]; 
     },
     false
  );
</script>
```

This is not the only way to do it, but its vanilla javascript/php, and [here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtr_webdev/d517eory/7/) with the basic logic (minus the PHP part)

Comment: thanks, it works well with js, but I could not make it work with php mysql, will check again with my codes.